# How to use over (partition by column name) in a snowflake UDF

Tags: function, window, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

**Problem Statement**

- There is a custom function (UDF in javascript) written in snowflake.
- This custom statement operates over a table with the window function over (partition by col name order by col name)
- GET_TEST1() is the name custom function

**Syntax:**
select GET_TEST1(Col1, Col2) over (partition BY col3,col4 order by col6+col7, col8 DESC) from table name WHERE IND='Y'

**Error:**
SQL compilation error: Invalid function type [???] for window function.

I am stuck with this, I went through multiple articles but am not able to resolve it can some one help me.

**UPDATES**

- I have gone through multiple articles and all of them convey
  over(partition by....order by....) will not work on custom functions.
- But the same query works in Netezza but not in Snowflake. Can some one guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check this docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions.html#partitions. Can you share with us a sample of your UDF definition?

Comment: This is the sample of the UDF create or replace function GET_TEST1 (col1 double,
col2 double,
)
returns double
language javascript as $$ //logic//$$;

Comment: Your function takes in two numbers and returns a number. That's it. It doesn't operate on a table, it operates on scalar values. As such, it makes no sense to introduce window function syntax here. Essentially, your assumptions about what you have built with this function, are incorrect. That being said, if you hit up that link that Felipe dropped you'll see that it IS possible to introduce window function syntax into your function call, but not on a scalar function. Your function needs to return a `table`, not a `double`. Your function also has to be called in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I have stumbled upon another problem decode(get_test1()) even that is not working so does this mean something is wrong with the UDF itself